# Outer index to ascending, inner index to descending in multi-index pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index dataframe which I was to sort_index.

For the outer index I want it to be in ascending order and for my second index I want it to be in descending order.

I tried

df is name of my dataframe

```
df.sort_index(level="outer")
df.sort_index(level="inner", ascending=False)
```

For each outer index there are 20 inner index.

Comment: Please add the definition of `df` in order the example to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's create a reproducible example.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: np.random.seed(1)
   ...: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]], names=['outer', 'inner'])
   ...: inds = list(range(len(index)))
   ...: np.random.shuffle(inds)
   ...: index = index[inds]
   ...: data = np.arange(len(index))
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=data, columns=['A'])
   ...: df
Out[1]: 
              A
outer inner    
1     3       0
      4       1
2     1       2
3     3       3
1     2       4
2     3       5
1     1       6
2     4       7
3     4       8
      2       9
      1      10
2     2      11
```

So pd.DataFrame.sort_levels doesn't allow us to sort levels in different orders at the same time, but we can sort them piece-by-piece and combine the results together.

```
In [2]: (df
   ...:  .sort_index(level='outer', sort_remaining=False)
   ...:  .groupby(level='outer').apply(lambda df: df.sort_index(level='inner', ascending=False))
   ...:  .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
   ...: )
Out[2]: 
              A
outer inner    
1     4       1
      3       0
      2       4
      1       6
2     4       7
      3       5
      2      11
      1       2
3     4       8
      3       3
      2       9
      1      10
```

Though since you don't describe your data, I don't know if it is possible in your case, with numeric inner-index values, you can achieve what you want by multiplying by -1, sorting both indices at the same time, and then multiplying by -1 again.